# request.getParameter is retrieving a 'null'

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to implement the CRUD functionality into my project. I am able to display the database table on the jsp but when I try to delete an entries, I get this error: (I see that there's an issue with a line in the servlet but don't understand why it isn't able to retrieve the bookingID.):

```js
Warning: StandardWrapperValve[UserController]: Servlet.service() for servlet UserController threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at com.daniel.controller.UserController.doGet(UserController.java:34)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Booking.java**

```js
package com.daniel.model;

public class Booking {
 
 private int bookingID = -1;
 private String bookingDate = null;
 private String reasoning = null;
 private String bookingStatus = null;
 private String bookingReview = null;
 
 public int getBookingID() {
  return bookingID;
 }
 public void setBookingID(int bookingID) {
  this.bookingID = bookingID;
 }
 public String getBookingDate() {
  return bookingDate;
 }
 public void setBookingDate(String bookingDate) {
  this.bookingDate = bookingDate;
 }
 public String getReasoning() {
  return reasoning;
 }
 public void setReasoning(String reasoning) {
  this.reasoning = reasoning;
 }
 public String getBookingStatus() {
  return bookingStatus;
 }
 public void setBookingStatus(String bookingStatus) {
  this.bookingStatus = bookingStatus;
 }
 public String getBookingReview() {
  return bookingReview;
 }
 public void setBookingReview(String bookingReview) {
  this.bookingReview = bookingReview;
 }
 @Override
 public String toString() {
    return "Booking [bookingID=" + bookingID + ", bookingDate=" + bookingDate
                 + ", reasoning=" + reasoning + ", bookingStatus=" + bookingStatus + ", bookingReview="
                 + bookingReview + "]";

 }


 
}
```

**BookingDao.java**

```js
package com.daniel.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.daniel.model.Booking;
import com.daniel.util.DbUtil;


public class BookingDao {
 
 private Connection connection;

    public BookingDao() {
        connection = DbUtil.getConnection();
    }

    public void addUser(Booking booking) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                    .prepareStatement("insert into booking(booking_id,booking_date,reasoning,booking_status) values (?, ?, ?, 'Upcoming' )");
            // Parameters start with 1
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, booking.getBookingID());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, booking.getBookingDate());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, booking.getReasoning());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void deleteUser(int bookingID) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                    .prepareStatement("delete from booking where booking_id=?");
            // Parameters start with 1
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, bookingID);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateUser(Booking booking) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                    .prepareStatement("update booking set booking_date=?, reasoning=?" +
                            "where booking_id=?");
            // Parameters start with 1
            preparedStatement.setString(1, booking.getBookingDate());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, booking.getReasoning());
            preparedStatement.setInt(3, booking.getBookingID());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<Booking> getAllUsers() {
        List<Booking> bookings = new ArrayList<Booking>();
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from booking");
            while (rs.next()) {
                Booking booking = new Booking();
                booking.setBookingID(rs.getInt(1));
                booking.setBookingDate(rs.getString(2));
                booking.setReasoning(rs.getString(3));
                booking.setBookingStatus(rs.getString(4));
                booking.setBookingReview(rs.getString(5));
                bookings.add(booking);
                System.out.println(booking);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bookings;
    }

    public Booking getUserById(int bookingID) {
        Booking booking = new Booking();
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.
                    prepareStatement("select * from booking where booking_id=?");
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, bookingID);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
              booking.setBookingID(rs.getInt(1));
                 booking.setBookingDate(rs.getString(2));
                 booking.setReasoning(rs.getString(3));
                 booking.setBookingStatus(rs.getString(4));
                 booking.setBookingReview(rs.getString(5));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return booking;
    }


}
```

**UserController.java**

```js
package com.daniel.controller;


import java.io.IOException;


import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.daniel.dao.BookingDao;
import com.daniel.model.Booking;

public class UserController extends HttpServlet {
 
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     private static String INSERT_OR_EDIT = "/user.jsp";
     private static String LIST_USER = "/listUser.jsp";
     private BookingDao dao;

     public UserController () {
         super();
         dao = new BookingDao();
     }

     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         String forward="";
         String action = request.getParameter("action");

         if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
          System.out.println(request.getParameter("bookingID"));
             int bookingID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("bookingID"));
             dao.deleteUser(bookingID);
             forward = LIST_USER;
             request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());    
         } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")){
             forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
             int bookingID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("bookingID"));
             Booking booking = dao.getUserById(bookingID);
             request.setAttribute("booking", booking);
         } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listUser")){
             forward = LIST_USER;
             request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
         } else {
             forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
         }

         RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
         view.forward(request, response);
     }

     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         Booking booking = new Booking();
         booking.setBookingDate(request.getParameter("bookingDate"));
         booking.setReasoning(request.getParameter("reasoning"));
         String bookingID = request.getParameter("bookingID");
         if(bookingID == null || bookingID.isEmpty())
         {
             dao.addUser(booking);
         }
         else
         {
            booking.setBookingID(Integer.parseInt(bookingID));
             dao.updateUser(booking);
         }
         RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(LIST_USER);
         request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
         view.forward(request, response);
     }


}
```

**listUser.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR" pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
<title>Show All Users</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border=1>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User Id</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>DOB</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th colspan=2>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${users}" var="booking">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${booking.bookingID}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${booking.bookingDate}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${booking.reasoning}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${booking.bookingStatus}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${booking.bookingReview}" /></td>
                    <td><a href="UserController?action=edit&userId=<c:out value="${booking.bookingID}"/>">Update</a></td>
                    <td><a href="UserController?action=delete&userId=<c:out value="${booking.bookingID}"/>">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p><a href="UserController?action=insert">Add User</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your link to delete uses the following URL:

```
UserController?action=delete&userId=<c:out value="${booking.bookingID}"/>
```

And your code uses

```
request.getParameter("bookingID")
```

So, obviously, the bookingID parameter is null, since there is no such parameter in the URL. The parameter is named `userId`.

Note that using a link to delete something is a very, very bad idea. Anyone can send you a link with the deletion URL, and if you click on it: Boom! you've deleted a user.

Worse: if that page ever gets public, the GoogleBot (and all the other search engine bots) will click on every link in the page to crawl your site, and thus delete every user.

Use a form, submitted with POST.

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera Voting here is a secret ballot. You have no evidence whatsoever as to who voted how, and no business speculating on it.

Answer (score 0):

In your template you set the links with the parameter `userId=<c:out value="${booking.bookingID}"/>`, then you try to read back the parameter with `request.getParameter("bookingID")`.

Since the parameter is named `userId` and not `bookingID` the call to getParameter returns null, a parameter with that name doesn't exist.

This can be fixed by making sure you use the same name in both places.